# How to print everything behind a match?

Tags: bash, shell

I need to print everything behind a match. In this case it's ' '.

Tried using `awk`, `sed` and `grep`. Every time it just printed everything before the match.

```
Comments (){
        line=$1
        comment=$(echo $line | sed -n 's/ //p')
        echo $comment
}

Comment="$(Comments $line)"
```

The input is like:

```
name.surname@email.com;KF-2514 WE NEED TO TALK A LOT
```

The output should be like:

```
WE NEED TO TALK A LOT
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your `sed` command simply removes all spaces. In addition, you need to quote the argument when calling the function: `Comment=$(Comments "$line")`, because it contains spaces. For debugging: In your function, do a `set -x` just before the first line and a `set +x` just after your last line, and add the output to your posting.

Comment: Correcting myself: Your `sed` command deletes the first space, not all spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

```
Comment="$(Comments $line)"
```

and line equals

```
name.surname@email.com;KF-2514 WE NEED TO TALK A LOT
```

the `$1` inside the function is set to `name.surname@email.com;KF-2514` and this is what you process. The correct way to invoke the function is

```
Comment=$(Comments "$line")
```

In addition, apply one of the suggestions outlined in the comments to correctly extract the part of the line you are looking for, for instance following the suggestion described by *jenesaisquoi*.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use parameter expansion, eg.

```
echo ${line#* }
```

deleting up to first space from front of string.

Comment: It just prints the "name.surname@email.com;KF-2514"

Comment: what does? if I assign you example string to `line` and run the above command it gives the output you expected, eg. `line="name.surname@email.com;KF-2514 WE NEED TO TALK A LOT"; echo ${line#* }`

Comment: @jenesaisquoi , I suspect the input data is not as advertised

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with that. I'm trying to solve this problem for more like 3 hours...

Comment: @FilipTrunda have you tried using `set -x` and debugging your script? Clearly, the input to `Comments` is not what you are expecting

Comment: No, I have not. I have got more than one function that works with the same line. And the others works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Using grep with `PCRE`:

```
echo "$line"| grep -oP '\s\K.*'
WE NEED TO TALK A LOT
```

Using `awk`:

```
echo "$line" |awk '{$1=""}1'
 WE NEED TO TALK A LOT
```

Using `sed`:

```
echo "$line" |sed -r 's/^[^ ]+//g'
 WE NEED TO TALK A LOT
```

Or, `sed` without `-r` flag:

```
echo "$line" |sed  's/^[^ ]\+//g'
 WE NEED TO TALK A LOT
```

You  may want to run your function like:

```
comments(){
    input="$1"
    echo "$input"|grep -oP '\s\K.*'

    }

    #pass the input line here
    comments "name.surname@email.com;KF-2514 WE NEED TO TALK A LOT"
```

Comment: Prints a blank space. Nothing else

Comment: can you please share how you are executing the command , as these are tested commands on my terminal .

Comment: ./tst.sh ./info.csv ./shared.csv 2.5.10 output.txt

Comment: this answer is suppose to be run like `echo "name.surname@email.com;KF-2514 WE NEED TO TALK A LOT" |grep -oP '\s\K.*'`

Comment: I know, sorry. The program is more complex... And yes, that's what going into it...

Comment: are you sure `$line` is getting defined properly , you can put an `echo "line=$line"` just before these commands to confirm that its not empty ?

Comment: can you try other answer from @jenesaisquoi ? , *if the input is incorrect* then it will also fail.

Comment: Tried. Different problem. Just print it before the match.

Comment: @FilipTrunda , your data in `$line` is not correct,  can you share what `echo $line` prints ?

Comment: Sure, why not.
pavel.vojtechovsky@unymra.com;release notes KC-3504
pavel.vojtechovsky@unymra.com;KC-3504 remove useless initHandler in DocumentList filter. 
The first one is not send to the function Comments.

Comment: @FilipTrunda , is there space just before `pavel` in the input  ?

Comment: No, it is not. I know it would make a mess.

Comment: last question before giving up , what is output of `echo ${line} |cat -A`, you can add the output in the question for better visibility so others can also help you

Comment: pavel.vojtechovsky@unymra.com;release notes KC-3504$
pavel.vojtechovsky@unymra.com;KC-3504 remove useless initHandler in DocumentList filter$

Comment: @FilipTrunda check the update , pass the string to `Comments` function

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is probably the space -- the code `line=$1` would set `$line` to *"name.surname@email.com;KF-2514"*.  So `sed` wouldn't see any space, and therefore wouldn't print a thing.

Try changing `$1` to `$@`, losing the variables which aren't needed, plus change the `sed` code a bit:

```
Comments (){  echo "$@" | sed -n 's/^[^ ]* //p') ; }

Comments 'name.surname@email.com;KF-2514 WE NEED TO TALK A LOT'
```

Output:

```
WE NEED TO TALK A LOT
```

To use the above function on a file named *foo*, try:

```
while read x; do Comments "$x" ; done < foo
```

But if a file was the input, it might be simpler to just use `sed` without any wrapper function:

```
sed -n 's/^[^ ]* //p' foo
```